# Why Hibernate doesn't save my object in database

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm using Hibernate 4.3.10 with Java 8.

To be more explicit see the following code example :

```java
public static long createBlindStructure(BlindStructure pBlindStructure){
    Transaction tcx = null;
    SessionFactory factory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    int id = -1;
    try{
        tcx = session.beginTransaction();
        id = session.save(pBlindStructure);
        tcx.commit();
    }
    catch( Throwable e){
        tcx.rollback();
    }
    finally{
        session.close();
    }
    return id;
}
```

In my mind this method `save()`  open session and transaction, save my object and close session and transaction. From `save()` I tried to get back the identifier as describe in javadoc. But It doesn't work, I see the request execute in my log (thanks to Hibernate debug mode).

```java
Hibernate: insert into PokerLeagueManager.blindStructure (structureJson) values (?)
```

But when I try this :

```java
public static long createBlindStructure(BlindStructure pBlindStructure){
    Transaction tcx = null;
    SessionFactory factory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    try{
        tcx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(pBlindStructure);
        tcx.commit();
    }
    catch( Throwable e){
        tcx.rollback();
    }
    finally{
        session.close();
    }
    return pBlindStructure.getIdBlindStructure();
}
```

It correctly saved my object.

I test one more case :
Just returning a constant and don't put Id in the variable like first example and It work. It seems that object is not save in case I get the ID directly with `session.save()` method.

Moreover, I observe something interesting. I made a first test with one of the solution which worked, it generated a database data with Id 117. Then I changed my code for the solution which difsn't work and reloaded it in Tomcat , I made 2nd try without success. I changed again my code for the one which succeded and the id was generated is 120. It missed 2nf id number (the 2nd try I've done ??)

To help you see my `hibernate.cfg.xml` file

```java
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
          '-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN'
          'http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd'>

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property     name='connection.driver_class'>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name='connection.url'>jdbc:mysql://XXXXXX:XXXX/PokerLeagueManager</property>
    <property name='connection.username'>XXXXX</property>
    <property name='connection.password'>XXXXXX</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">120</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">10</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">120</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts">1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryDelay">250</property>
    <!--  Dev -->
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.validate">true</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name='dialect'>org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</property>

    <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>


    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name='show_sql'>true</property>
    
    <mapping resource="mappings/BlindStructure.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="mappings/Tournament.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="mappings/LegalFee.hbm.xml"/>
</session-factory>
```

Edit: User3813463 answer for a part of a question. It explains that session are in AUTO flush mode by default which flush session in some case like :

> flush occurs by default at the following points:
>
> - before some query executions
> - from org.hibernate.Transaction.commit()
> - from Session.flush()

But I my point of view (I maybe miss understand something), my first case should worked because I commit my transaction.

Secondly, I need advise to choose a flush mode. To my mind Commit mode is a good way to do for method which make only inserting or only reading data on database.

Do you agree with me, have you some sources where this is debate?

Comment: If you don't mind first can you answer to my question, what you see on console/log when line ` return pBlindStructure.getIdBlindStructure();` get executed? :)

Comment: ...and also post your hibernate configuration...

Comment: pBlindStructure.getIdBlindStructure() => it return the value of generated Id in my second case. I had hibernate configuration on main message

Comment: Why don't you try with `session.flush()` before `transaction.commit()` in first case.

Comment: Didn't work. But i finally found why it doesn't work. I return me an Integer and not a Long. I don't paid attention and no one notify me that I didn't have any logger .... In fact my code throw an exception. Thanks for all your suggestion :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This all is the magic of `FlushMode` read docs [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/FlushMode.html)

According to docs default `FlushMode` is `AUTO` that means

> The Session is sometimes flushed before query execution in order to
>   ensure that queries never return stale state.

According to another document ([Here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-flushing)):

> `flush` occurs by default at the following points:
>
> before some query executions
>
> from org.hibernate.Transaction.commit()
>
> from Session.flush()

So when you say pBlindStructure.getIdBlindStructure(); hibernate actually perform flush on current session, resulting data is getting saved in DB.

Comment: Sorry if don't answer, I will study your answer later today I had no time last day.

Comment: Sorry for the answer delay, I had lot of think to do IRL ;). It explains why in my second case i'm sure to have the resulot. But I My first case a transaction commit which should flush the current session? In that case, why it's not flush at all?  Which flush mode is the better to use in low concurrency application?

Answer (score 0):

The session save method returns an object for the generated id by the generator. This value you should cast to `Long`.

```
long id = -1;
try{
    tcx = session.beginTransaction();
    id = (Long) session.save(pBlindStructure);
    tcx.commit();
}
catch( Throwable e){
    tcx.rollback();
}
finally{
    session.close();
}
return id;
```

Comment: Sir, but what about why record is not getting saved at method 1. i think it's because of `flushmode`. I think at second method when `pBlindStructure.getIdBlindStructure();` gets executed session get flushed to write (insert) record to DB.

Comment: Sorry i forgot my cast but I did exactly like you during my test (eclipse don't let me the choise)

Comment: I didn't get what are you saying.

Comment: I forgot the cast for "session.save" in my exemple but I during my test I had it.